# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined foundation.magellan.js line 46

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, magellan

I am getting an error of, uncaught error when i click on any of the sub-navs, on my foundation magellan navigation.
it is showing that top is not defined on the line 46 of the foundation.magellation.js please give any solution for the above.

//Account for expedition height if fixed position

```
     var scroll_top = target.offset().top - settings.destination_threshold + 1;//error
     scroll_top = scroll_top - expedition.outerHeight();
```

html:start

```
   <DIV class="row">
   <div data-magellan-expedition="fixed">
   <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li data-magellan-arrival="home"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li data-magellan-arrival="catalogue"><a href="#catalogue">Catalogue</a></li>
        <li data-magellan-arrival="about"><a href="#js">About Us</a></li>
        <li data-magellan-arrival="contact"><a href="#js">Contact Us</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   </div> 


  /*end*/ 
  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.magellan.js"></script>
   <script>
   $(document).foundation({
       "magellan-expedition": {
       active_class: 'active', // specify the class used for active sections
       threshold: 0, // how many pixels until the magellan bar sticks, 0 = auto
       destination_threshold: 10, 
       throttle_delay: 50, // calculation throttling to increase framerate
       fixed_top: 0, // top distance in pixels assigned to the fixed element on scroll
   }
    });
    $(document).foundation();
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Can we see your html and js configuration for this feature?

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of the bottom `$(document).foundation();`? It seems extraneous.

Comment: yes, it doesn't create any problem, though!

Comment: Are you including jQuery anywhere in that document? It's [required by Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html)...

Answer (score 0):

Add data-magellan-destination attributes that correspond to the items in the sub-nav. It's trying to figure where it needs to scroll to and there is no target defined. For example, you might have sections further down the page with the attribute:

```
<div data-magellan-destination="home">home content here</div>
<div data-magellan-destination="catalogue">catalogue content here</div>
```

etc.